# Using D3 transitions disables hover CSS on SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have some circles that I want to change fill when I hover over them. I give them "pins" class and here's the CSS for them:

```
.pin {
    fill: #9ecae1;
    stroke:#3182bd;

}
.pin:hover{
    fill:steelblue;
}
```

Each pin has a value and I want to include some transition so that if there is a change in that value, the circles will momentarily flash some other color, green for instance. They work fine without the update. After the update, the hover no longer works.

Here is my code for the transition:
d[2] is just some key name.

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(points, function(d) {return d[2];})
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .style("fill", "green")
  .attr("r", function(d) {return 5 + 10*Math.ceil(radius(d[3]));})
  .each("end", function(d){
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .style("fill", "#9ecae1");
  });
```

I was able to pinpoint that setting style("fill", xxx) disables the hover but why? And is there a way to get the momentary transition while still maintaining the hover?

Comment: Could you develop a fiddle, then we'll do something on this...

Comment: To make a "simplified" version I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5PHSc/ based on http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch10.html#_click_to_sort. 

So when you click on the bars, there should be a transition which makes the  bars move and turn red. However, the hover property is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem, that is in the below code

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(points, function(d) {return d[2];})
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .style("fill", "green")
  .attr("r", function(d) {return 5 + 10*Math.ceil(radius(d[3]));})
  .each("end", function(d){
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .style("fill", "#9ecae1");
  });
```

we are applying the color by using inline style, this inline is more priority than external css, So don't apply the color by using inline style instead use the attribute(fill) to fill the color, the line of code we have to change is remove `.style("fill", "green")` and replace it with `attr("fill", "green")`
and `.style("fill", "#9ecae1")` with `.attr("fill", "#9ecae1")`
Below is the modified code

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(points, function(d) {return d[2];})
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("fill", "green")
  .attr("r", function(d) {return 5 + 10*Math.ceil(radius(d[3]));})
  .each("end", function(d){
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .attr("fill", "#9ecae1");
  });
```

:)